# Combine Two Formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I want to combine a formula that disregards cells where there is a 0 in order to average and also to disregard cells where there is an error such as DIV/0.

I have these two formulas which achieve either of these functions but not both. How would I combine them?

```
{=AVERAGE(IF(ISNUMBER(M2:P2),M2:P2))}
=AVERAGEIF(M2:P2,"<>0")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would simply add the criterion of the second to the first:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(ISNUMBER(M2:P2)*(M2:P2<>0) ,M2:P2))
```

This is still an array formula and as such needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter.  If done properly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Answer (score 0):

you could use an if() to check for either condition then use the appropriate average function.
@Scott : better than mine...